# Connecting Apple TV HD to a monitor over USB-C port

Tags: display, appletv

Does Apple TV HD support connecting to a display via USB-C port? I use the same display with my newer MacBook Pro with USB-C port.

I use a [display](https://www.lg.com/in/monitors/lg-29UM69G) with three input options, a DisplayPort, an HDMI port and a USB-C port. I am able to connect my MacBooks using any one of them i.e., Mini Display Port to Display Port and HDMI cable on a 2013 15" MacBook Pro and a USB-C to USB-C cable on a 2019 16" MacBook Pro.

I have the HDMI port engaged with the MacBook and I wondered if I can connect the Apple TV HD to the display via USB-C, but turns out I can not get anything to appear on the display. I am able to connect the Apple TV to my 16" MacBook Pro using the same USB-C cable fine.

Does Apple TV not support outputting to a display over USB-C? Is there anyway to enable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the Apple TV does not support outputting to a display over USB-C. There's also no way to enable that as the hardware to do so simply isn't there.

The USB-C connection can only be used for USB data transfers (such as for example upgrading firmware, connecting to Xcode debuggers or similar).